# How to update the legend from matplotlib toolbar

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, legend

I am defining a matplotlib plot for a given data. once the plot is displayed, I am trying to change some line property using navigation tool bar edit option.

When I make change say example solid line to dashdotted, the update get reflected on the lines, but the legends are not updated.

How can I capture this event when the apply button is clicked, so i can use this to refresh the legend. At the moment I am capturing a pick_event as a signal to refresh the legends.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')


x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
y=np.linspace(100,200,100)
plt.plot(x,y,label='test')
plt.legend()
ax.legend()
plt.show()
#optional code
def on_press(event):
    lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(lines, labels, loc=0)
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_press)
```

[image: Plot image from the above code]
[image: Plot Image showing modifying line type]
[image: Plot Image showing the legend is not modified]

Comment: Your question is confusing... and your example doesn't really help (it doesn't do anything). You probably meant to put `fig.canvas.draw()` in your event.  But mainly, what exactly do you want this example to do?

Comment: I have edited my example. All I wanted to do is to update the legend when the plot marker type or line type is modified for a plot using the figure edit option

Comment: Ah I see - the example does what you want but you want a smarter way, yes?  I know the issue of refreshing legends came up last year, but if/how it was pursued I don't know.  I don't know enough about the NavigationToolbar innards to look for event handling from it, so I'll leave that to someone who does.

Comment: YES. I can do this at the moment using the event and handling option of the PyQt backend in matplotlib. There are signals to catch these events but they are all related to actual figure canvas. I want to know if there is signal when "figureoption apply button clicked". If so then i can catch the signal to perform a legend refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of struggle the only easy way to resolve this solution is to add legend refresh as part of the navigation tool bar call back function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

def home_callback():
    print "home called"
    ax.legend()

x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
y=np.linspace(100,200,100)
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,label='test')
ax.legend()
plt.show()

fm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()

fm.toolbar.actions()[0].triggered.connect(home_callback)
```